# Add full screen button to code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I suggest adding a "Full screen button" underneath code blocks.

For example in this post:
[I get java.lang.VerifyError using FontAwesome in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824801/i-get-java-lang-verifyerror-using-fontawesome-in-javafx)

The first code block, "Error", is very long and also spans to the very right. If I want to read a whole line I need to scroll down the screen for the horizontal scroll bar, then scroll right. Or mark the line forward and backward for each line.

2nd option is to have the bottom horizontal scroll-bar reachable from the top lines or shrink the block's window as the user demand so it will be reachable.